# Is it possible to create mobile responsive font-sizing in email HTML&CSS?

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I have a design that currently looks very squished on mobile because the font sizes are so big. My audience is split 50/50 on desktop & mobile readership.

Is there a way for me to create responsive font sizes? Can I scale font-sizes down to 80% when viewed on mobile?

Let me know if this is possible

I've tried adding the below code to get the font to adjust, however it did not budge.

```
 <style type="text/css">@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
     @-ms-viewport { width:320px; }
     @viewport { width:320px; }
     body {font-size:80%; }
     }
```

I expect font-size to scale down by a specified %, such as 80% on mobile.

Answer (score 3):

To add a mobile specific font size to your email text, use a media query to set the `font-size` at a certain screen size. A responsive “fluid” way to do this is to use the viewport width unit (`vw`) instead of pixels.

`Viewport-width` uses 1% of the viewport width as the standard size from which to work from. For example, the `viewport-width` of an iPhone7 is 750px, therefore `1vw` is `7.5px`. In this case, we set `font-size: 2vw` to get `15px`. This is responsive to screen size; as a viewport gets bigger or smaller the font will be responsive.

Along with `font-size`, we need to also adjust the `line-height` to ensure it is consistent. Experimenting with the number here can give different outcomes, and in the case above, `line-height:3vw` is enough to ensure the text isn’t squished.

To ensure the font doesn’t become too big, we add it to a class within a media query that will only work on a smaller viewport size. To ensure the `font-size` in our media query displays, we include `!important` to override the inline font style. Check out the example code below:

```css
<style type="text/css">
@media screen and (max-device-width:640px), screen and (max-width:640px) {
.mobfont {
font-size: 2vw!important;
line-height: 3vw!important;
}
}
</style>
```

Then, we add the class `mobfont` to any text we want to resize:

`<td style=”font-family: ‘Timmana’, Helvetica, Arial, san-serif;” class=”mobfont”>Responsive Text</td>`

More info here if you need it. https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/best-font-for-email-everything-you-need-to-know-about-email-safe-fonts

Comment: Note that [@media](https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=%40media) and [vw unit](https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=vw) are not supported by a bunch of email clients like Outlook on Windows